# Triangles incident on a vertex (Graphs)

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory

I am working on a project that requires specific methods on a graph class. Two of the methods requires this:

1.`numberOfTrianglesIncidentToVertex`, calculates and returns the number of triangles incident to vertex v. The algorithm below calculates the number of triangles incident for all graph vertices (V is the set of vertices, E is the set of edges):

```
 foreach v in V
     foreach pair of vertices (p, q) in AdjacencyList(v)
         if (p, q) is in E then add 1 to triangles[v]
```

2.`listOfTrianglesIncidentToVertex` calculates and returns the list of triangles incident to vertex v. A triangle should be specified by its vertices.

I have no idea what a triangle is in regards to the vertex and graphs. Can someone give me a thorough explanation. I would prefer a more lamens/ no big words explanation.

Comment: This kind of triangle? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph

Comment: I think that is the type of triangle.

Comment: Then it's exactly what it sounds like. Consider the vertices adjecent to your vertex. If any two of them are adjecent to each other then those two and your vertex are a triangle.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on stackoverflow, though. If you're still confused after reading Wikipedia, try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: how does that algorithm apply though?

Comment: Is the question what sort of algorithm you should use? If that's the case, give us some idea of what you tried, what you're thinking, and such. I really don't know what your question is as written.